# Why is 'logjam' the answer to 'function held up by traffic blockage'?

Tags: wordplay, crossword-clues, explanation

Why is 'logjam' the answer to 'function held up by traffic blockage'?  I guess 'log' is function, and logjam is blockage but why 'jam/maj'? L,G & A are all correct.

Comment: Does the clue have a question mark? If it doesn't, it is really weak.

Answer (score 5):

I fear it may just be that "jam" = "traffic" (= "traffic jam"). This would be a pretty weak clue, since the use of "jam" in what passes for the wordplay is pretty much the same as the final definition, but some crossword clues *are* pretty weak.

Comment: As mentioned in comment to OP, "function held up by traffic blockage?" feels reasonable, but without the question mark, totally agree.

Comment: So that would mean 'traffic blockage' was the clue to both a PART of the answer and the WHOLE answer - yes, that's really bad.  In the'The Times', too!  It's not what it was!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm suggesting that "traffic" clues JAM as part of the wordplay and "blockage" clues LOGJAM for the definition, so nothing's actually being used twice. But a pretty shoddy clue, if I'm understanding it right.